# SEO effects of H1 carousel slider

Tags: seo, web-development, web-crawlers, googlebot

I maintain a website for a law firm. Originally their main desired keyword was "zoning attorneys." So I created a small banner that has an `h1` "ZONING ATTORNEYS" on every page with the attorneys' names inside that `div`. This approach has worked well and yielded positive SEO results.

```
<aside class = "attorneys-container">
  <div class = "attorneys-heading-container">
    <h1 class = "attorneys-heading">ZONING ATTORNEYS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class = "attorney-top">
    <a href = "{{ site.baseurl }}/attorney-profiles.html">Joe Smith</a>
  </div>
  <div class = "attorney-bottom">
    <a href = "{{ site.baseurl }}/attorney-profiles.html">John Smith</a>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Now their desire is to focus on several keywords including:

- Zoning Attorneys
- Real Estate Attorneys
- Probate Attorneys
- etc...

My initial thought is to create something similar to a carousel image slider, which would have these multiple `h1` tags cycle through.

My assumption is that as long as I design the `h1` slider to only have one `h1` active on the actual html document. Such as when you click 'Inspect Source,' it would only display the active `h1`. Then, there would be no penalty for having multiple `h1` tags because there really is only one, just different strings going in to that `h1` every couple of seconds. Is this a correct assumption or am I missing something?

Also, let's say a crawler indexes my site once a week. The first week the crawler indexes "Zoning Attorneys" in the `h1`. The second week the crawler indexes "Probate Attorneys", and so on. Would this fluctuate the rankings of my site for these keywords in a negative way or would the crawler understand what I was doing?

Comment: If the multiple h1 tags are in your code, you will have a problem. It does not matter what you do with them. As well, do not chase keywords. Create fully semantic header tags (sentences) and only have one h1 tag. Do not play around with trying to influence search engines. Just create honest and traditional content.

Comment: @closetnoc If there is only one h1 tag, but the string contained is changed every couple of seconds by javascript. Would this have a negative result?

Comment: No. But only the one in the HTML code will be seen by the search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Myth : Adding keywords in class name, does not affect in SEO i.e. CSS class name does not count as keywords of content.

Slider note: There are tons of portal/news site using slider in viral content, but only few of them using [next and prev tag](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) in article, and those who have implemented that tags is performing well in search result. But those good article are divided into gallery parts, like 10 pictures of {{Actress Name }} in Las Vegas - 1 Photo, 2 Photo and so on. And all of slider using same h1 tag like you, but the only difference in last keywords ( like 1 photo or 2 photo). So I did not recommended to use slider for your keywords, because it is not related, so google might be treat your webpage as low quality.

If I was there, then I will use these codes into my static generator.

```
<div class = "attorney-top">
    <a href = "{{ site.baseurl }}/attorney-profiles.html#joe-smith">Joe Smith</a>
  </div>
  <div class = "attorney-bottom">
    <a href = "{{ site.baseurl }}/attorney-profiles.html#john-smith">John Smith</a>
 </div>
```

And jump those links into specific profile ID or just use different url for different profile(If profile page has no more content, so simiply use noindex meta tags).

Comment: In response to the first part of your answer. Are you saying that class names in css have an effect on SEO?

Comment: I edit my first line, hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

By trying to rotate in a Headline - you'll simply rate poorly for several terms instead of well for one.

If you rank for the most popular substring ("Attourneys") and then create more content keyed for each sub-heading ("Probate Attourneys") then you'll have more success. This will give you some credit on substrings while gaining significant equity to rank on longtails.

If you have content for three different areas - split it into three pages and link it from the front page with the anchor being the keyword. By trying to rotate things in, you're lowering the amount of Google visible content instead of increasing it - which is counter productive to getting ranked!